# stat_bin() plot with logarithmic scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a following plot with logarithmic y-scale that I plotted using **ggplot2** in **R**.

[image]

```
convergencePlot = ggplot(allCosts, aes(x=V2))
finalPlot = convergencePlot + stat_bin() + scal_y_log10()
```

When I plot this I get the following warning:

```
Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0
```

1. I do not understand this warning. How can I remove this warning?
2. I see that the plot starts form 1 for all values of x except some where it starts from 0 and end at 1 (red circle). Is this an error?
3. Some x-values that I see on the extreme left (I guess 77 and 76) are not present in my original data. How can I remove those values? (green circle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very difficult to answer this question without some sense of what's in your actual data, but here's a guess at least:

Try `+ stat_bin(drop = TRUE)` instead.

Comment: The data that i have is basically a list of numbers. The **x axis** represents those numbers while the **y-axis** is the log of number of times each of the x-value is repeated. I used the log scale to make sure that the values that are very low can also be visible in the graph.

Comment: @Ankit Yes, that much is quite obvious, but not terribly helpful. That's why we generally request that people provide a _reproducible_ example, complete with data and code.

Comment: `drop` is deprecated. Please use `pad` instead. but `pad` does not seem to drop anything whethere it is set to true or false.